# how to use source code from google git

Tags: android

I just download the source code from google git, but when I run it always there is a problem and could not walk properly,

is there a special way for the setting or whatever it is that the code runs fine?

Comment: I think the best way is use dependency

Comment: You can clone the project using clone url

Comment: @teck-wei >>> is there an example of her, I was just learning and will not understand it

Comment: @mdg5435 
whether there are differences in the clone with the download?

Comment: Yes. You can clone the project from IDE terminal. It will be downloaded and opened when cloned successful.

Comment: I've done it, but all the code does not seem to work correctly, always there is an error and could not run ...